# Recommended way to show loader for for the whole screen

Tags: flutter

There are multiple ways you can show loading bar till data is not fetched. Some are:

Use setstate((){}) method.
Use State Management like GetX, Bloc, Provider.
Use FutureBuilder()
Use StreamBuilder()

I understood the recommended way are with builders becuase problems like setState when widget dispose and etc... wont happen.
I want to show loader untill all my async methods in my widget page tree are done and it cant be done with future builder.
I think on a way where i every async widget notify page provider and when all page async methods finish i show the page.
Is my approach good?.
For this to happen i extend state with safe state like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class SafeState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {
  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    super.setState(fn);
  }
}
```

demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:info_striker/models/initialize-screens/initialize_team_screen.dart';
import 'package:info_striker/widgets/loader-return-types/loader.dart';

import '../widgets/loader-return-types/load_error.dart';

class FutureBuilderContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final RequestHandler requestHandler;
  final Widget? child;
  const FutureBuilderContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.requestHandler,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (requestHandler.loading) {
      return const Loader();
    } else if (requestHandler.failed) {
      return LoadError(error: requestHandler.error);
    } else {
      return child ?? const SizedBox();
    }
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:info_striker/future_builder/future_builder_container.dart';
import 'package:info_striker/locator.dart';
import 'package:info_striker/models/initialize-screens/initialize_team_screen.dart';
import 'package:info_striker/models/services/synced_teams_service/top_scorer.dart';
import 'package:info_striker/screens/team/team-top-scorers/team_top_scorers_view.dart';
import 'package:info_striker/services/synced_teams_service.dart';

class TeamTopScorersContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  int teamId;
  int seasonId;

  TeamTopScorersContainer({
    Key? key,
    required this.teamId,
    required this.seasonId,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TeamTopScorersContainer> createState() => _TeamTopScorersContainerState();
}

class _TeamTopScorersContainerState extends SafeState<TeamTopScorersContainer> {
  RequestHandler _requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
  List<TopScorer> _topScorers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTopScorers();
  }

  getTopScorers() async {
    try {
      _topScorers = await locator<SyncedTeamsService>().getTeamTopScorers(widget.teamId, widget.seasonId);
      setState(() {
        _requestHandler.onSucceess();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _requestHandler.onFail(e);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilderContainer(
      requestHandler: _requestHandler,
      child: _requestHandler.loading
          ? null
          : TeamTopScorersView(
              topScorers: _topScorers,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that I wrote a while ago. This is the simplest implementation that I know of, that can be used from any screen.

The first argument is the context of the widget from which you are calling this function. The second argument is where you provide a future, basically you can provide a `Future<Response>` if you are fetching data or anything else according to your scenario. The third argument is a function that will be executed after the loading circle is closed. This can be optional if you don't need such functionality.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Call this function to show the loading circle
void startLoading<T>({
  required BuildContext context,
  required Future<T> future,
  required Future<void> Function(BuildContext loadingContext, T result) then,
}) async {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
    builder: (newContext) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          return false;
        },
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: future
            ..then((T value) {
              Navigator.of(newContext).pop();
              then(context, value);
            }),
          builder: (futureContext, snapshot) {
            return const Dialog(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
              child: SizedBox.square(
                dimension: 40,
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

`WillPopScope` is used to prevent the user from pressing the back button and closing the loading circle. So only `Navigator.pop(context)` works to go back if you use this widget. You can remove this widget if you want users to be able to exit the loading circle by pressing the back button.